# canon d340 printer - how do I get it stay on letter size paper

Tags: printer

How do I get my canon d340 printer to stay on letter size paper.  It changed to legal size and I can't get to change back.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please clarify what you are asking. Did you change the paper size physically, in the software you are printing from (i.e. Word) or within the printer settings directly? Also, is this at home or on a corporate network?

Answer (score 0):

To set printer defaults, go to Printer Properties, click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button. Set the required properties in there and click OK. Now click the General tab, and the Preferences button. Check that the changes are reflected there. If not, set it there as well. Then click OK.

If printing via a server, defaults need to be set on the server. All this assumes you are running Windows. If not, please tell us which OS.

Some applications, like Word, save the paper size with the document. Hence a legal size document will always print that size, until you change it via Page Setup. The print size will not even change if you change printer properties at print time: Word will just ignore that change.

And, if your question is about something completely different, please provide more details.